# `Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable bytes` and `address is 0 bytes after a block of n bytes alloc'd`

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

Valgrind is giving me bizarre output that goes away if more memory is allocated. In my program, the number I have to add to make it go away is `2064`. This number appears nowhere in my program, and I have been up and down the thing for a few hours now trying to find where I could have gone wrong. No luck. Everything seems airtight, and I see no reason why an extra 2064 bytes of memory should be needed.

Thankfully, I managed to reproduce the bug in a minimal program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    /* 8500 is a number I chose that is just above the generated executable size (8472)
     * I double-checked after compiling and the executable is still under 8472 bytes
     * You may have to choose a different size.
     */
    unsigned char *p = malloc(8500);
    unsigned char *pp;
    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[0], "rb");
    ssize_t nread;

    if(p == NULL)
        return 1;

    pp = p;

    while((nread = fread(pp, 1, 4096, fp)) > 0)
        pp += nread;

    free(p);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of valgrind (and wc):

```
$ gcc wtf.c -Wall
$ wc -c a.out
8472
$ valgrind ./a.out
==31142== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==31142== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==31142== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==31142== Command: ./a.out
==31142==
==31142== Syscall param read(buf) points to unaddressable byte(s)
==31142==    at 0x4F4E151: read (read.c:27)
==31142==    by 0x4EC9741: _IO_file_xsgetn (fileops.c:1364)
==31142==    by 0x4EBD4A0: fread (iofread.c:38)
==31142==    by 0x1087CF: main (in /home/braden/code/git/bfvm2/src/a.out)
==31142==  Address 0x5231174 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8,500 alloc'd
==31142==    at 0x4C31B0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31142==    by 0x108782: main (in /home/braden/code/git/bfvm2/src/a.out)
==31142==
==31142==
==31142== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31142==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31142==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 13,148 bytes allocated
==31142==
==31142== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31142==
==31142== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==31142== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Any ideas? I don't believe there's any undefined behavior here. This isn't preventing my program from running, but it's driving me crazy, and I don't want it to turn into something serious in the future.

Comment: apologies for the title. I didn't think "bizarre valgrind error" would be a good title. Please note that this is *not* a duplicate question. I've seen both of those and neither of them helped. Plus, it seems like the error is happening somewhere that's out of my control.

Comment: Please show the size of `a.out`

Comment: @kaylum It's in the code comment: 8472 bytes

Comment: valgrind is complaining about a call to malloc and a call to fread, and only under these conditions, which confuses me. Consider that the file I/O happens *after* malloc has been called, yet valgrind is complaining about malloc. How is this possible when the call to malloc by itself has nothing wrong with it?

Comment: @kaylum I added `wc` output to the question

Comment: My guess: you are telling it to read up to `4096` bytes on the last iteration but the buffer can't hold that many bytes. So it can *potentially* overflow even though it doesn't in this case.

Comment: instead of `4096` pass min of 4096 and the amount of buffer remaining

Comment: @BradenBest valgrind is complaining about writing past the end of the allocated space, not complaining about the call to malloc

Comment: @M.M what do you mean? `fread(buf, size, nmemb, fp)` attempts to read `nmemb` bytes and returns (as an `ssize_t`) the number of bytes written to `buf`. Thus the final read is expected to be less than or equal to `nmemb`

Comment: Yes, you are currently requesting 4096 bytes when there is not that much space in the buffer, so to avoid this problem you should not request more bytes than there is space in the buffer (regardless of the status of the file)

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Lemme try changing the block size from 4 KiB to 1 KiB since the buffer size is always a multiple of 1KiB. I'll let you know

Comment: That would still have the same problem just on a smaller scale. The constant `4096` should be replaced by an expression that does not exceed the space remaining in the buffer.  (Alternatively you could read to a fixed buffer and then copy to the destination buffer the amount read)

Comment: @M.M you magnificent bastard, [it worked!](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/769430851695280149/846961924775477259/unknown.png) Please write that into an answer, and I'll mark it as accepted straight away

Comment: @M.M apologies, I wasn't clear. What I meant was that I would try that block size change directly with my actual program, where the buffer sizes are guaranteed to be a multiple of 1 KiB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valgrind message indicates an attempt to write past the end of the allocated space.

This could be coming from the call to `fread` requesting `4096` bytes when there is not that much space remaining in the buffer -- even though there may only be a few characters left in the input stream.

The C Standard isn't entirely clear on this matter but regardless of that it seems either:

- your compiler is taking the liberty of writing to some other locations within the `4096` requested that are past the end of the allocated space, or
- Valgrind is reporting an error for passing the incomplete buffer to system call `read`, even if the `read` call wouldn't have written past the end.

To avoid this, make sure the maximum extent passed to `fread` does not exceed the remaining buffer size, e.g. `fread(pp, 1, MIN(4096, (p + 8500 - pp)), fp)` where MIN is the usual minimum macro.

Comment: "it seems your compiler is taking the liberty of writing to some other locations within the 4096" yikes! I was right to push for an answer on that error instead of giving up. That's a class of UB I hadn't considered at all. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily conclude that the code/compiler is actually writing past the end of the buffer. More likely it is valgrind that is making that assessment with a basic bounds check.

Comment: Agreed. Sounds a lot like undefined behavior to me. In this case, it just happened to produce a program that does what I want, but valgrind saw the error. I suspect on a different platform, compiler, hardware, etc, Maybe even with a much larger discrepancy between the amount requested and the amount left over, that this could lead to a crash.

Comment: @kaylum the valgrind output indicates that system call `read()` was made with the start position beyond the buffer ?

Comment: @M.M Possibly, but that is not how I read it. Notice: `byte(s)`. It wouldn't have `(s)` if it were just referring to the starting address. Also, the OP test case does have valid start addresses AFAICS.

Comment: @kaylum OK, that is possible